# Vifm - Jump to file in an existing instance of Vifm

Tags: client-server, vifm

Is there a way to make an existing instance of Vifm to jump to a specific file using `--remote` argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`:goto`](https://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-%3Agoto) command, which locates a path. Alternatively there is [`--select`](https://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm---select) command-line option, but it enters directories instead of positioning cursor on them (files are handled as in `:goto`). Examples:

```
# terminal #1
vifm --server-name test

# terminal #2
vifm --server-name test --remote +'goto /etc'
vifm --server-name test --remote --select /etc/fstab
```